# mvc3 change authentication value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have stored authentication info inside the `User.Identity.Name` once the user log in to the system. using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1150085/926460) method

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Id + " | " + Name + " | " + Language + " | " + Culture + " | " + Email + " | " + Role+ " | " + TimeOffset+ " | " + Rights, RememberMe);
```

Now I want to change the some value inside `User.Identity.Name` when user change some configutation setting, eg `Language`

But after calling the `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()`, the value inside the `User.Identity.Name` does not change anymore

```
string identity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name; // modify current value
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(identity, false); // assign new value
```

How can I change this value?

Answer (score 1):

`SetAuthCookie` updates the cookie containing the FormsAuth ticket with the updated value, but it does not set the `User` of the current context. You can change the user of the current context by creating a new `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity`. It's as simple as getting the current `HttpContext` and setting the `User` property.

You'd normally do this in an `IHttpModule` or Global.asax.cs in the `PostAuthenticateRequest` event, because at this point FormsAuth will already have authenticated the user's ticket and set the identity. After this event, the new `IPrincipal` you created will be available to the application for the remainder of the request.

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var application = (HttpApplication)sender;
    var context = application.Context;

    if (context.User != null || !context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return; // user not authenticated, so you don't need to do anything else

    // Here, you'd process the existing context.User.Identity.Name and split out the values you need. that part is up to you. in my example here, I'll just show you creating a new principal
    var oldUserName = context.User.Identity.Name;
    context.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(oldUserName, "Forms"), new string[0]); 
}
```

As an aside, I don't recommend packing values in the identity name, but rather the ticket's `UserData` property. In that case, you can check if the `context.User.Identity` is `FormsIdentity` and access `Ticket.UserData`:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var application = (HttpApplication)sender;
    var context = application.Context;

    if (context.User != null || !context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return; // user not authenticated, so you don't need to do anything else

    var formsIdentity = context.User.Identity as FormsIdentity;

    if (formsIdentity == null) return; // not a forms identity, so we can't do any further processing

    var ticket = formsIdentity.Ticket;

    // now you can access ticket.UserData
    // to add your own values to UserData, you'll have to create the ticket manually when you first log the user in

    var values = ticket.UserData.Split('|');

    // etc.
    // I'll pretend the second element values is a comma-delimited list of roles for the user, just to illustrate my point
    var roles = values[1].Split(',');


    context.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(ticket.Name, "Forms"), roles); 
}
```

[Here](http://www.danharman.net/2011/07/07/storing-custom-data-in-forms-authentication-tickets/) is some more info on creating FormsAuth tickets with custom values in UserData.